# Возведение в степень в JavaScript

Tags: javascript

Пишу калькулятор на JavaScript.

Задача: умножить число на само себя n-ное число раз.

Но как это сделать?

Вот сам код

```
var operation = prompt('What operation will we do?');
var num_1 = parseInt(prompt('Enter 1-st number'));
var num_2 = parseInt(prompt('Enter 2-nd number'));
if (operation == '+') {
    var result = num_1 + num_2;
    alert('Result is: ' + result);
} else if (operation == '-') {
    var result = num_1 - num_2;
    alert('Result is: ' + result);
} else if (operation == '/') {
    var result = num_1 / num_2;
    alert('Result is: ' + result);
} else if (operation == '*') {
    var result = num_1 * num_2;
    alert('Result is: ' + result);
} else if (operation == '%') {
    var result_1 = Math.floor(num_1 / num_2);
    var result_2 = num_1 % num_2;
    alert('Result is: ' + result_1 + ', ' + 'remainder is: ' + result_2);
} else if (operation == '**') {
    var result ==
} 
else {
    alert('Invalid operation!')
}
```

Comment: a ** b, Math.pow(a, b); выбирай

Answer (score 1):

Используйте [Math.pow()](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Math/pow)

```js
const powResult = Math.pow(5, 2)
console.log(powResult)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
function pow(a, n) {
  return a ** n;
}

console.log(pow(2, 3));
```